# ASP.NET not rendering full layout

Tags: c#, asp.net

So, I am in the transition of moving my ASP.NET application from Razor to React.

This is the layout of my body at the moment:

```
<body>
<script>
    var isAuthorized = true;
</script>
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "__AjaxAntiForgeryToken" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
<div id="navBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top" />
<div class="container-fluid contentContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="profile" class="profileContent col-2"/>
        <div class="bodyContent col-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="col-1" id="friendList"/>
    </div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Chat");}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../wwwroot/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

What already works is having the navBar item being rendered by React in the backend. However, the whole part after it, so the part containing:

```
    <div class="container-fluid contentContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="profile" class="profileContent col-2"/>
        <div class="bodyContent col-9">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <div class="col-1" id="friendList"/>
    </div>
    @{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Chat");}
</div>
```

is missing when checking the finished page in my browser. This whole div is just not being rendered.

I know this post does not give off a lot of information to work with, but this is mostly due to me having no idea what I could give you to start with.

I will gladly take any ideas why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I can't believe I didn't spot this.

The problem lies within using a self-closing div as in

```
<div id="navBar" class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top" />
```

After this element the rest is disposed as it seems.